# How to handle this copy-paste question?

Tags: discussion, support

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1190051/rational-inequalities-problem-solving-questions?noredirect=1#comment2422950_1190051) I found a copy-paste question. How should we handle this case? (also read the comments)

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't have the ability to vote to close and if you really think it should be looked at, you can flag the question as missing context. Click flag post and you will see

[image]

Choose off topic and then you will see

[image]

Click the radio button and submit.

As a note, the question in the background was the first question I came across so I used it as an example. I am not passing any judgment on the merits of that question just providing an example.